# Why can I not loop over a dictionary / array of keys

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop

Update: I tried logging like this: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.idTitleDict))` as suggested by @Kobe. This shows empty curly braces… All the code regarding this dictionary (declaration, populating it) is posted below. I first call `this.getTemplates()` to populate the dictionary, then the next line i want to iterate over it. It seems it is empty at that point when I log it to console after passing the dict to `JSON.stringify()`.

In the ngOnInit method of a component in my angular app I loop over a dictionary to get the first key and then break out of the loop. But it seems it doesn’t get iterated over.

dictionary looks like this:

```
{
  1: "title",
  2: "title",
  3: "title",
  4: "title",
  5: "title",
  6: "title"
}
```

I tried:

```js
const keys = Object.keys(this.idTitleDict);
for (const key in keys) {
  if (this.idTitleDict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key);
      this.showContent(key);
      break;
    }
  }
```

also:

```js
for (const key in this.idTitleDict) {
      if (this.idTitleDict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key);
        this.showContent(key);
        break;
      }
    }
```

also:

```js
for (const key in Object.keys(this.idTitleDict)) {
      if (this.idTitleDict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key);
        this.showContent(key);
        break;
      }
    }
```

Nothing get’s logged to the console and `this.showContent()` doesn’t get executed. I know for sure the dictionary is populated since I checked that. In another function I loop over another dictionary and that goes without issues:

```js
getTemplates() {
    this.apiService.getTemplates().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        for (const key in data) {
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this.idTitleDict[key] = data[key].title;
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

the full ngOnInit method:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.getTemplates();
    const keys = Object.keys(this.idTitleDict);
    console.log(this.idTitleDict); // this shows the dictionary is populated as shown in the dictionary at the top of this post
    for (const key in Object.keys(this.idTitleDict)) {
      if (this.idTitleDict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key);
        this.showContent(key);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

declaration for the dictionary:

```js
idTitleDict: { [id: string]: string; } = {};
```

it get’s filled in this method:

```js
getTemplates() {
    this.apiService.getTemplates().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        for (const key in data) {
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this.idTitleDict[key] = data[key].title;
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

I probably missed something but I’m at my wits end.

Comment: Where is the list you want to iterate?

Comment: @Ntwobike I want to iterate over the dictionary shown in the first 3 codeblocks, I’ll update the post showing how to dictionary looks

Comment: What does `keys` array contains after the init?

Just for the record - the `if` for `hasProperty` is redundant as you're already iterating the existing keys...

Comment: Also, this snippet should suffice:

```js
 Object.keys(this.idTitleDict).forEach(this.showContent)
```

Comment: You should use an array looking at your structure.

Comment: @Aviad the keys array as I have just seen is empty after init…

Comment: @Aviad I don’t want to call the `showContent()` method for each element, only for the first one

Comment: Then are you sure `this.idTitleDict` has any values on `ngOnInit`?

Comment: put a debugger; statement in your code and then debug it

Comment: The structure shown in your first codeblock (the dictionary) is not a valid Javascript object. Please make sure you post the right thing ... or maybe this is the issue already?

Comment: @devnull69 that is incorrect

Comment: @devnull69 That is how it gets shown in console, what would be a better way to view the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems object does not have data when code executes. try this to confirm.

```
let self = this;
setTimeout(function(){
  const keys = Object.keys(self.idTitleDict);
  for (const key in keys) {
    if (self.idTitleDict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key);
        self.showContent(key);
        break;
      }
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: wait wait wait, this actually worked! Please explain why :)

Comment: I would like to add though that `this.showContent(key);` has to be changed to `self.showContent(key)` to make it work

Comment: object was not having data at that time...how you are getting this object?

Comment: I get the data from a rest api. How is it that when i replace the for loop i tried in `ngOnInit()` with your code the dictionary does suddenly have data?

Comment: this keyword refer to current object and when you use settimout it will take settimout this. but that is not the reason.

Comment: that object is binded after the code execution. and when you gave settimout its executes after the data binding was successful.

Comment: If you are calling rest API in same ts file ..its better to give this code after succes of the rest api . Rest will take time as it is async .

Comment: Please edit your answer and change `this.showContent(key);` in the for loop to `self.showContent(key)`  since `this.showContent(key);` throws a TypeError.

Comment: You can try to do like this if rest function is there in ts same ts code.                                                getTemplates(){
this.apiService.restApiCallApi().pipe(first())
.subscribe(
response => {
 if(response .success == true){
  this.idTitleDict = response.data;
const keys = Object.keys(this.idTitleDict);
if(keys.length){
this.showContent(keys[0]);
}

 } 
},
error => {
this.error = error.error.error;
});
}

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to call the method for the first key, why don't you simply do  like below

```
const keys = Object.keys(this.idTitleDict);
if(keys.length){
    this.showContent(keys[0]);
}
```

Comment: It appears that when i make the keys array it doesn’t get populated. even though the dictionary definitely is

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `[0]` to only call `showContent` on the first item:

```js
const obj = {'1': "title1", '2': "title2", '3': "title3", '4': "title4", '5': "title5", '6': "title6"},
  showContent = console.log

showContent(Object.keys(obj)[0])
```

Another approach would be to use a for loop and immediately break:

```js
const obj = {'1': "title1", '2': "title2", '3': "title3", '4': "title4", '5': "title5", '6': "title6"},
  showContent = console.log

for (var key in obj) break
showContent(key)
```

Comment: I need the first key not the value

Comment: this returns an undefined object `Object.keys(obj)[0]`

Comment: I will update my post with the init of the dictionary, maybe someone sees something wrong with the dictionary itself

Comment: When you log the object, use JSON.stringify(obj), so that chrome doesn't modify it when it is logged.

Comment: when I execute `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.idTitleDict))` it just shows empty curly braces in the console: `{}`

Comment: That means your object is empty at the point where you are logging the object, hence why are receiving this error.

Comment: Hmm, that seems odd. How is that when I don’t use `JSON.stringify()`  at the exact same line in my code with `console.log()`  it does show a populated dictionary?

Comment: @keesjanbertus thats because of chrome trying to be useful and automatically updating it for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195984/discussion-between-kobe-and-keesjanbertus).

Answer (score -1):

As `Object.keys()` return type is `Array`, you should use **for..of** loop instead of **for...in**, which in this case returns array of indexes, but not object keys.

The main problem is that `this.getTemplates()` acts asynchronous (fetching data from API always is), and object is empty at that time, so working with dictionary should be moved to another lifecycle hook (OnChanges, maybe).

Comment: But the it returns undefined